# Preg_matche youtube id issue

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm working on a small php script.
I have used preg_match to grab youtube id from a long text.
Any way i'm using this code :

```
preg_match('~/v/([0-9a-z_]+)~i', $text, $matches)
```

The code work perfectly but he dont grab ids which containt "-".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a `-` in your regular expression, it should be:

```
preg_match('~/v/([0-9a-z_\-]+)~i', $text, $matches)
```

Comment: Thank you worked perfectly i need to wait 11 minutes to choose it as good answer thank you so much.